# TSQL update check if null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql that keep give me an exception, and i can not figure out why, my quess is that the avg(x.Points) return null for some reason, how can i make it return 0 in that case?

```
    UPDATE a
SET a.Points = (SELECT avg(x.Points) FROM 
   (SELECT TOP 5 * 
    FROM [dbo].[AlbumImages] i 
    WHERE i.AlbumId = a.Id 
    AND i.Points > 0 
    ORDER BY i.Points Desc) x)
FROM  [dbo].[Albums] a
    join [dbo].[Users] u on a.UserId = u.Id
WHERE u.DoRanking = 1
```

This gives me the exception

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Points', 
table 'Cosplay.dbo.Albums'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

Comment: do a case when on (SELECT avg(x.Points) FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [dbo].[AlbumImages] i WHERE i.AlbumId = a.Id AND i.Points > 0 ORDER BY i.Points Desc) x)

Comment: Maybe of interest, the reason that you're getting NULL is that there are no values. `AVG` on an empty set is `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check with [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) on the AVG function. ISNULL takes a second parameter to return when the expression is null.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Points = (SELECT ISNULL(avg(x.Points),0) 
                FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * 
                      FROM [dbo].[AlbumImages] i 
                      WHERE i.AlbumId = a.Id 
                      AND i.Points > 0 
                      ORDER BY i.Points Desc) x)
FROM  [dbo].[Albums] a
    join [dbo].[Users] u on a.UserId = u.Id
WHERE u.DoRanking = 1
```